# Critical points of a function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

I have a question to solve about maxima and minima on a closed interval, and in this question gave this first step:
1- find the values of f on critical points
And to do this, you take the function and take the derivative of the function, but what if the derivative of the function is just the number 3? That means that the function does not have critical points?

Comment: Yes, since $3\neq0$, though the function can still have a maximum or a minimum on a closed interval

Comment: How can a straight line $\neq 0$ have critical points

Answer (score 1):

"Critical points" or a function are defined as points at which the derivative is 0 or does not exist.  If the derivative is the constant, 3, then it is never 0 and exist for all x.  Yes, if the derivative is the constant, 3, then the function has **no** critical points.